# Is there any chance to remember Activity stack so when I start app next time I have same Activity stack?

Tags: android

Is there any chance to remember Activity stack so when I start app next time I have same Activity stack ? For example when I start app I am on Activty_1, then I go on Activity_2 and then on Activity_3 when I stop app ( home button, app is in background until system removes app). When I start app next time I need to be on Activity_3 and when click back_button ( there is back_button on every layout on my activities and call just `finish();` ) to go on Activity_2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app has been completely shutted down and fresh started next time (from either app launcher or recently used list), AFAIK, there is no easy solution to retain Activity stack (it is actually called back stack from Android official dev giude) as it always get fresh created every time you fresh start your app.

If your app has been sent in background (by home button) and started next time (from either app launcher or recently used list) which is actually bring your standby app to foreground. The default configuration [android:launchMode="standard"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) should gives the exact behaviour you described.

The behaviour of back stack navigation is quite flexible and adjustable via numbers of configuration settings, A worth reading from official dev guide talk ablout [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html).